# Jsoup Cookies for HTTPS scraping

Tags: java, cookies, web-scraping, jsoup

I am experimenting with this site to gather my username on the welcome page to learn Jsoup and Android.  Using the following code

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mikeportnoy.com/forum/login.aspx")
    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$Login1$UserName", "username", "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$Login1$Password", "password")
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();
String sessionId = res.cookie(".ASPXAUTH");

Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mikeportnoy.com/forum/default.aspx")
.cookie(".ASPXAUTH", sessionId)
.get();
```

My cookie (.ASPXAUTH) always ends up NULL.  If I delete this cookie in a webbrowser, I lose my connection.  So I am sure it is the correct cookie.  In addition, if I change the code

```
.cookie(".ASPXAUTH", "jkaldfjjfasldjf")  Using the correct values of course
```

I am able to scrape my login name from this page.  This also makes me think I have the correct cookie.  So, how come my cookie comes up Null?  Are my username and password name fields incorrect?  Something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 53):

I know I'm kinda late by 10 months here. But a good option using Jsoup is to use this easy peasy piece of code:

```
//This will get you the response.
Response res = Jsoup
    .connect("url")
    .data("loginField", "login@login.com", "passField", "pass1234")
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();

//This will get you cookies
Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

//And this is the easieste way I've found to remain in session
Documente doc = Jsoup.connect("url").cookies(cookies).get();
```

Though I'm still having trouble connection to SOME websites, I connect to a whole lot of them with the same basic piece of code. Oh, and before I forget.. What I figured my problem is, is SSL certificates. You have to properly manage them in a way I still haven't quite figured out.

Comment: This solution is not working for me, can you please clarify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73572751/jsoup-login-cookies-are-not-working-with-sub-pages-but-only-with-home-page

Answer (score 19):

I always do this in two steps (like normal human),

1. Read login page (by GET, read cookies)
2. Submit form and cookies (by POST, without cookie manipulation)

Example:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mikeportnoy.com/forum/login.aspx")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mikeportnoy.com/forum/login.aspx")
        .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$Login1$UserName", "username")
        .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$Login1$Password", "password")
        .cookies(response.cookies())
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .execute();

Document homePage = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mikeportnoy.com/forum/default.aspx")
        .cookies(response.cookies())
        .get();
```

And always set cookies from previuos request to next using

```
         .cookies(response.cookies())
```

SSL is not important here. If you have problem with certifcates then execute this method for ignore SSL.

```
public static void trustEveryone() {
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }}, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me, can you please clarify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73572751/jsoup-login-cookies-are-not-working-with-sub-pages-but-only-with-home-page

Comment: I did exact same steps but it's not working, can you please look into above query

Comment: "..If you have problem with certifcates then..." how to know this ? Also please clarify when I'm using cookies in Step 3, how do I debug why is it not logging in ?

Answer (score 1):

What if you try fetching and passing all cookies without assuming anything like this: [Sending POST request with username and password and save session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206133/sending-post-request-and-save-cookies/7206268#7206268)

If you still have problems try looking in to this: [Issues with passing cookies to GET request (after POST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897524/issues-with-passing-cookies-to-get-request-after-post/7908622#7908622)

Comment: I tried the first link and was able to get back three cookies, but one was blank.  The cookie I needed wasn't there, which explains why I always get NULL.  I can't figure out why my code doesn't return all of the cookies I see in firebug.  Is there anything that I can look for?