# how to maintain variable cookies and sessions with jsoup?

Tags: java, session, cookies, jsoup

```
public boolean isGood(String path)
{
    if (p != path)
    {
        good = false;
    }

    if (good)
    {
        try 
        {
            Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(path);
            Map<String, String> cookys = Jsoup.connect(path).response().cookies();

            if (cookys != cookies)
                cookies = cookys;

            for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) 
            {
                connection.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
            }

            Doc = connection.get();
            good = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            rstring = e.getMessage().toString();
            good = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Response response = Jsoup.connect(path).execute();
            cookies = response.cookies();
            Doc = response.parse();
            good = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            rstring = e.getMessage().toString();
            good = false;
        } 
    }       
    return good;
}
```

This method is not right. What I'm trying to figure out is a way to without know what cookies will exist, be able to handle cookie changes as well as maintain sessions.

I'm writing an app for my simple machines forum, and it changes its cookie config as you click around for some custom behavior.

But if the app does well for my site, I was going to publish a version for others to use for other forums.

I know I'm heading in the right direction, but the logic is kind of kicking my butt.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In addition to BalusC's comments, it's unlikely that `p != path` thing is what you really mean, although it's *possible*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code is very confusing. The flow is illogical and the exception handling is bad. The object reference comparisons like `if (p != path)` and `if (cookys != cookies)` makes no utter sense. To compare object's **contents** you need to use `equals()` method instead.

To the point, I understand that you want to maintain cookies in a bunch of subsequent Jsoup requests on the same domain. In that case, you need to *basically* adhere the following flow:

```
Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();

// First request.
Connection connection1 = Jsoup.connect(url1);
for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
    connection1.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
}
Response response1 = connection1.execute();
cookies.putAll(response1.cookies());
Document document1 = response1.parse();
// ...

// Second request.
Connection connection2 = Jsoup.connect(url2);
for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
    connection2.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
}
Response response2 = connection2.execute();
cookies.putAll(response2.cookies());
Document document2 = response2.parse();
// ...

// Third request.
Connection connection3 = Jsoup.connect(url3);
for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
    connection3.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
}
Response response3 = connection3.execute();
cookies.putAll(response3.cookies());
Document document3 = response3.parse();
// ...

// Etc.
```

This can be refactored to the following method:

```
private Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();

public Document get(url) throws IOException {
    Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url);
    for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
        connection.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
    }
    Response response = connection.execute();
    cookies.putAll(response.cookies());
    return response.parse();
}
```

which can be used as

```
YourJsoupWrapper jsoupWrapper = new YourJsoupWrapper();

Document document1 = jsoupWrapper.get(url1);
// ...

Document document2 = jsoupWrapper.get(url2);
// ...

Document document3 = jsoupWrapper.get(url3);
// ...
```

Note that the upcoming Jsoup 1.6.2 will come with a new `Connection#cookies(Map)` method which should make that `for` loop everytime superfluous.

Comment: i thank you very much. i searched and searched for an example of the right way to do it. this way is definitely better than the way i was attempting. lol

Comment: Someone from the future! for some reason I found JSoup to be very convenient. Just my two cents are that in the current JSoup library there's a method named cookies (Map<String,String> cookies) that does the addition of the key/value pairs. So the above foreach can be replaced for: connection.cookies (cookies)

Comment: you can do connection.cookies(cookies) instead of the for loop

Comment: @crl: Indeed, see also last paragraph of above answer and the comments of Jsoup developer on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7206268/157882).

Answer (score 1):

+1 for BalusC

I changed some in your code and it works for me, so you get cookie from site and only than get Document

```
public Document get(String url) throws IOException {
    Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
    Connection.Response response = connection.execute();
    connection.cookies(response.cookies());
    return connection.get();
}
```