# jsoup connect parameter

Tags: java, httpclient, jsoup

I access a webpage by passing the session id and url and output is a HTML response.
I want to use jSoup to parse this response and get the tag elements. 
I see the examples in Jsoup takes a String for establishing connection. How do i proceed.

pseudo code:

I tried the above method and got this exception

```
java.io.IOException: 401 error loading URL http://www.abc.com/index
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:387)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:364)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:143)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:132)
```

Basically the `entity.getContent()` has the HTML response which has to be passed as a String to the connect method. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons HttpClient and Jsoup do not share the same cookie store. You basically need to pass the very same cookies as HttpClient has retrieved back through Jsoup's `Connection`. You can find some concrete examples here:

- [Sending POST request with username and password and save session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206133/sending-post-request-and-save-cookies)
- [how to maintain variable cookies and sessions with jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728447/how-to-maintain-variable-cookies-and-sessions-with-jsoup)

Alternatively, you can also just continue using HttpClient for firing HTTP requests and maintaining the cookies and instead feeds its `HttpResponse` as `String` through `Jsoup#parse()`.

So this should do:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient1.execute(httpget, httpContext);
String html = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, testUrl);
// ...
```

By the way, you do not necessarily need to create a whole new `HttpClient` for a subsequent request. Just reuse `httpclient` which you already created. Also your way of obtaining the response as `String` is clumsy. The second line in the above example shows how to do it at simplest.

Answer (score 0):

It shows an http error 401 which means

`Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided`.

Therefore, i think you need to login into the website using your java code or identify yourself by sending cookies through your code.

Comment: I have edited my pesudo code. Youc an see that i have logged in to the website and passed the cookies.