# JSoup take too long to load & sometimes doesn't fetch the correct data

Tags: java, jsoup

I am facing two problems when using JSoup to scrape data from the web:

1. It's performance is not that good: it takes a bit too long to connect to a URL.
2. For some sites, it's not fetching the correct data from the URL. For example, try any URL of the NY Times, like — http://www.nytimes.com/2014/06/13/technology/facebook-to-let-users-alter-their-ad-profiles.html?ref=technology

It just loads the login page, but when I try the same URL on the Google or Facebook, they correctly fetch the data. Also, the URL loads fine in a browser for a guest user.

Comment: NYT requires that your application is able to deal with coockies - otherwise your request gets redirected to the login page as far as I know. Similar threads on this topic: [Extract NYT articles using JSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078520/extract-new-york-times-articles-using-jsoup) and [How to manage cookies using JSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069288/how-to-manage-cookies-with-jsoup). Also this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie) might be of interest for you

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the NY Times is using a session cookie to determine if they should show you the content, or redirect you to the login page.

Because JSoup is dropping the cookies, you'll always retrieve the log-in page, rather than getting sent back to the content.

According to the JSoup docs, you can retrieve the cookies on the response using the [`cookies()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Base.html#cookies%28%29) method.

You can then set them on your next request with the [`cookies(Map<String, String>)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#cookies%28java.util.Map%29) method on Connection.

You can then manage the cookies in your request/response chain.

---

This isn't specifically a JSoup issue, you can reproduce the same thing with curl on the command line:

```
curl -v http://www.nytimes.com/…
```

Returns a "See other" request with the location of the login page

```
curl -v http://www.nytimes.com/glogin?URI=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F…
```

Drops a cookie & gives a "302" request to send you back to the page.

If I request the page again, I'll start the process over, unless I send their session cookie along with my request.