# Access same name cookie in different application tabs

Tags: java, jira, confluence, jira-plugin

I have an application running on **localhost:8080** and it create a cookie with name **jsessionid**. Now I need to open another tabs for different application which is running on **localhost:8090** which also create a cookie with same name that is **jsessionid**.

I need to access cookie of first application tab in second application tab..

how can I access both cookies... many tried but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a servlet filter that would run before page gets rendered (in the atlassian-plugin.xml)

`<servlet-filter name="My Filter" i18n-name-key="home-page-redirect-filter.name"
        key="home-page-redirect-filter" class="mypackage.CookieFilter"
        location="before-dispatch" weight="100">
        <description key="home-page-redirect-filter.description">Some     description</description>
        <url-pattern>WHEN_TO_RUN</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </servlet-filter>`

and then you can intercept cookies

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    Cookie[] myCookies=request.getCookies();
    //do something with cookies
}
```

Comment: Hi Panos.. thanks for your fast reply, implement as you suggest me but still not getting previous application tab **(localhost:8080)** cookie, i think its becouse of request object which is requesting from **localhost:8090**... how can i get it from browser....

Comment: having **context path** for both the appliaction.. will it help in getting cookie..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I misread your question. JSESSIONID is an httponly cookie and you won't be able to use document.cookie in the javascript to get it. 
Maybe take a look at [Jsoup Cookies for HTTPS scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139178/jsoup-cookies-for-https-scraping/16129860#16129860) and [Sending POST request with username and password and save session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206133/sending-post-request-and-save-cookies/7206268#7206268) for some ideas.